# Cut rectangle into 2 pieces

Tags: math, polygon

Let's say you have to cover an opening that's 2 feet wide and 12 feet
long. All you have is a sheet of plywood 3 feet wide and 8 feet long. How
can you cut the sheet into 2 pieces which will cover the hole perfectly?

Comment: You'll have to use a saw.  SO is not the right place for carpentry questions.  Off-topic.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I dunno, maybe some really accurate karate chops. Or some water jets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
OOOOXXXXXXXX
OOOOOOOOXXXX

xxxxxxxx
ooooxxxx
oooooooo
```

This will do it.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you look at the areas, they are the same. What you can do is lop off a foot, so you have a 1'x8' piece and a 2'x8' piece.  Then you cut the smaller piece in half, where you have three pieces, two 1'x4' and one 2'x8'.  Find a way to brace it and you're done.

Comment: Wait, saw that it is two pieces.

Comment: 'lop off a foot' -- this is precisely why one should not seek or provide carpentry advice on SO.  Geeks like us will, given the opportunity and a sharp tool, easily lop off a hand or a foot.  Stick to your keyboard.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark 'lop' is a technical sawing term.

Comment: And 'foot' is technical anatomical term.

Comment: And both together is the recipe for a fun time, or a trip to the hospital.